# Is Parts faster than Apply?

Tags: performance-tuning, benchmarking

Consider a function that accepts a coordinate `f[x,y,z]`. Our aim is to apply this function to a list of coordinates, at scale, as fast as possible.

Here are the three versions of (an e.g.) `f`

```
r`f = Compile[{x, y, z}, x + y + z]
r`f[x_,y_,z_]:=x+y+z
r`f=Function[{x,y,z},x+y+z]
```

and the 2 ways of applying it

```
r`pts = RandomReal[1, {10^6, 3}];

(*Method 1*)
r`f @@ # & /@ r`pts; // RepeatedTiming

(*Method 2*)
Table[r`f[pt[[1]], pt[[2]], pt[[3]]], {pt, r`pts}];//RepeatedTiming
```

The times I got:

|  | @@ | [[ ]] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Compiled | $2.79978$ | $0.293673$ |
| Function | $4.13239$ | $0.325191$ |
| := | 2.80247 | 2.76107 |

So Parts is better than Apply for both `Compile`d and `Function` while only slightly so for `:=`.
Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: even faster: ``r`f = Compile[{x, y, z}, x + y + z, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]`` and then ``r`f @@ Transpose[r`pts]; // RepeatedTiming``

Comment: @Roman works but I got $2.98,.29$ so comparable to non Listable. You sure about the speed up?

Comment: Like @Roman, I get very fast execution from his code using Version 12.2 on Windows 64x.

Comment: @bbgodfrey relative to other constructs as executed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, comparable to `Table[r`f[pt[[1]], pt[[2]], pt[[3]]], {pt, r`pts}]`.  By the way, `r`f @@@ r`pts` is three times faster than `r`f @@ # & /@ r`pts` with your Method 1 but still quite slow comparted to `Table . . .` or @Roman's approach.

Comment: By the way, I have not checked whether Mathematica uses multiple processors when executing any of these methods.  Sometimes, Mathematica does use multiple processors for inherently parallel computations.

Comment: And, `Total[r`pts, {2}]` is the fastest of all by a factor of nearly three.  The moral of this is to focus on optimizing `f`.  Nice question, though. (+1)

Comment: @bbgodfrey caution: this is an example construction...my specific use case is calculating field at xyz form 1000's of sources so can't use `Total` ;(...i just wanted to see how this part could be optimized...thnx for the help though

Comment: I know `Prefix`and `Postfix` , but never seen functiondefinition "r`f " ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann ```r`f``` is just a symbol in the context ```r`*``` There are more details on [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html).

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks. Didn't know that "`" is allowed in a symbol name.

Answer (score 1):

All your function calls seem time-constrained by the overhead of data-retrieval and function-calling, not by the function itself. For speeding up operations, it's important to limit the number of function calls and pass big chunks of data around. Then, the discussion of the speeds of `Parts` vs `Apply` becomes moot.

For example, by passing the entire lists to your function and then operating on lists, a massive speedup results:

```
r`f = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}, {z, _Real, 1}}, 
              x + y + z,
              CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

r`pts = RandomReal[1, {10^6, 3}];
r`f @@ Transpose[r`pts]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0155405    *)
```